# Enviar variable desde el controlador a una vista

Tags: php

Estoy enviando una variable desde mi controlador a una vista de la siguiente manera :

> $this->load->view('pagar_en_linea', $valorPagar) en Codeigneiter;

Pero al recibirla y mandarla a imprimir me genera este error:

> Undefined variable $valorPagar

He buscando en internet y esa es la manera correcta de enviar variables

Comment: Cuál es el error que obtienes, podrías agregarlo en tu pregunta?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el error

Comment: Por favor, copia y pega el error en su totalidad para entender a que te refieres.

Comment: Listo ya añadi la imagen del error

Comment: Puedes poner todo el codigo de como envias la variable `$valorPagar` porque parece que no lo esta recibiendo, no esta definida

Comment: Mensaje, variable no definida `valorPagar`. Esto quiere decir, que primero, antes de usarla, debes definirla.

Comment: como la defino? la estoy enviando asi $this->load->view('pagar_en_linea', $valorPagar); y la uso con <?php echo $valorPagar ?> pero nose como definirla antes de usarla?

Comment: Que contiene `$valorPagar`? Porque al definirlo solo es esto: `$valorPagar = 50`, despues recien envias tu variable a la vista

Comment: Si eso ya lo hice la defini antes asi  $valorPagar = '0,00'

Comment: Deberías agregar el código de `pagar_en_linea.php`

Comment: <form action="https://checkout.wompi.co/p/" method="GET">
  <!-- OBLIGATORIOS -->
  <input type="hidden" name="public-key" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="MONEDA" />
  <input type="hidden" name="amount-in-cents" value="<?php echo $valorPagar ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="reference" value="" />
  <!-- OPCIONALES -->
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect-url" value="URL_REDIRECCION" />
  <button type="submit">Pagar con Wompi</button>
</form>

Comment: solo tengo eso en el php de pagar_en_linea.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo de `Welcome.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución es que desde la vista se debe enviar un array

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar lo siguiente:

```php
$this->load->view('pagar_en_linea')->with('valorPagar', $valorPagar);
```

Comment: me genera error :/

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::with()

Answer (score 0):

Amigo prueba en enviarlo encapsulado en un array es decir

```
$envio['valorPagar'] = $valorPagar;
$this->load->view('pagar_en_linea', $envio);
```

En la vista si la imprimes como `$valorPagar`